# Not able to use Supabase Hook to read data from database into react-table with react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-query, supabase-database

This is the error I get : `TypeError: observer.getOptimisticResult is not a function`

I'm trying to work with React-Query and Supabase to read data into a React-Table. I've created a `useReadData.ts` hook as shown below:

```
export default function useReadData(table_name, startRow, endRow) {
  return useQuery(
    ["read_data"],
    () =>
      supabase
        .from(table_name)
        .select("*")
        .range(startRow, endRow)
        .then(handleSupabaseError)
        .then(({ data }) => data)
  );
}
```

I have called this hook in my `index.tsx` file within the `App()` component:

```
function App() {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = React.useState(0);

  const fetchIdRef = React.useRef(0);

  const fetchData = React.useCallback(({ pageSize, pageIndex }) => {

    if (fetchId === fetchIdRef.current) {
      const startRow = pageSize * pageIndex;
      const endRow = startRow + pageSize;
      const table_name = "company";

      const data = () => useReadData(table_name, startRow, endRow);
      console.log(data);
      setRowData(data);
      setPageCount(10);

      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

I've spent weeks, but I'm not able to resolve this error. Please help!

Comment: It seems like you're violating the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) by calling your custom hook inside `useCallback` conditionally. May I ask why you're not using the supabase API directly?

Comment: Won't I benefit from wrapping the supabase function in useQuery()? Since React-Query handles local caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach.

1. You're invoking a hook conditionally inside another hook, which breaks the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)
2. You're trying to store a function instead of an array inside `setRowData`

Here's an alternate approach:

`index.ts`

```
interface Range{
  startRow: number;
  endRow: number;
}

function App() {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [range, setRange] = React.useState<Range>()

  const fetchIdRef = React.useRef(0);

  const fetchData = React.useCallback(({ pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
    const startRow = pageSize * pageIndex;
    const endRow = startRow + pageSize;
    setPageDetails({ startRow, endRow });
  }, []);

  const { data } = useReadData("company", range?.startRow, range?.endRow, fetchIdRef)

  useEffect(() => {
    setRowData(data)
    setPageCount(10);
    setLoading(false);
  },[data])
}
```

`useReadData.ts`

```
export default function useReadData(table_name, startRow, endRow, fetchIdRef) {
  return useQuery(
    ["read_data"],
    () => {
      // I don't know the source of fetchId, maybe you can pass it in the hook too?
      if (startRow && endRow && fetchId === fetchIdRef.current)
      return supabase
        .from(table_name)
        .select("*")
        .range(startRow, endRow)
        .then(handleSupabaseError)
        .then(({ data }) => data)
      
      // To avoid returning Promise<void>. You can handle this in the useEffect as well
      return Promise.resolve([])
    }
  );
}
```

I'm not that familiar with `react-query`, so let me know if there's a problem in this.

Comment: It's throwing another error where I'm creating the react-table instance : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`

Comment: I'm making a new post with a little more clarity on the new error I'm facing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884591/error-reading-data-from-supabase-into-react-table-with-the-help-of-react-query)

Comment: Alright. If my answer resolved your original question regarding fetching data from supabase, it would be great if you could vote it and mark it as solved.

Comment: Done. Thanks you!